# Why it is showing `missing ',' before newline in composite literal`

Tags: go

Why my vscode is showing this error
`missing ',' before newline in composite literal`

My code:

````golang
if title == "" && desc != "" {
            msgs = database.UpdateNotification(&Notify, map[string]interface{}{
                "Description": changedDesc,
            }); msgs != nil {
                log.Info("error while deleting notification")
            }```
````

Comment: Could you please clarify your question by providing a sketch of the code you'd like to write? I'm not sure what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to able to change the variable names dynamically?

There isnt any way of doing this. I suggest if you really need somthing like that you would use a Map.

```
Data     map[String]String
```

Im not exactly sure what you need this for, or if this helps.